# Apache Airflow - HttpHook vs. direct Python's requests library usage and their relation to DAG refreshing

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I've recently joined a team as a DAG developer. I can see that we currently use Python's requests directly instead of using HttpHooks in our code. We create a requests.Session object to share it across different requests but since *min_file_process_interval* is set to 30 seconds by default this session is recreated every 30 seconds which doesn't make much sense.

Will using HttpHook help in this case? Are hooks somehow left out of this DAG refreshing process? They also create a requests.Session object underneath.

Also, the APIs which we are calling require an access token which expires after some time. Currently we fetch a new access token each time we make an API call but it would be best to fetch the token only if the previous one has expired. But again, DAGs are refreshed every 30 seconds. So how to prevent the token from being cleared when the DAGs are refreshed?

Both the token retrieval and requests.Session object creation is done in a utils.py module used as a plugin in Airflow DAGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpHook` and you can use request directly. Both are fine and it's up to you. In general using `HttpHook` should makes your life easier (you can also subclass it and enhance it)
In any case you should use the code inside `PythonOperator` and not as top level code thus the `min_file_process_interval` is not relevant.

To explain with example

It's OK to do

```
def func():
    HttpHook(...).run(...) # or requests.get(...)
 
with DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule=None):

    PythonOperator(
        task_id='places',
        python_callable=func,
    )
```

In this example the `HttpHook` (or `requests.get`) will be invoked only when the operator is running.

Never do:

```
with DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule=None):
    
    HttpHook(...).run(...)  # or requests.get(...)
```

In this example `HttpHook` (or `requests.get`) is called every time the DAG is parsed (`min_file_process_interval`) which means that the end point is called every 30 seconds. Big no for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Just one question: is it possible to preserve requests.Session object between task executions or will it be recreated each time a task is run (either with HttpHook or requests)? Our tasks run very frequently and it would be nice not to create the session each time. Also, we need to get a token before sending each request. The token is valid for some time, so the same question applies here: can we keep the token between different tasks executions? Or maybe I'm just looking at it the wrong way trying to optimize everything. I'm quite new to Airflow...

Comment: Tasks may run on different machines thus they are not sharing memory/disk. Tasks can communicate with Xcom which is a string stored in the database. If you are looking for ways to optimize a specific path you have chosen I think it's best to open a new question and focus on the specific issue.